# Refused to apply style from 'https://checkout.paystack.com/static/css/app.ae95f4402c6c43208071.css' Paystack

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate Paystack payment gateway and suddenly i am getting below errors:

```
 popup:1 Refused to apply style from 'https://checkout.paystack.com/static/css/app.ae95f4402c6c43208071.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
 popup:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://checkout.paystack.com/static/js/app.f4f3340418415473b1b9.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

It was working fine before and suddenly its not showing the payment proccess form.

Can anyone help me and let me know any known reason behind this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The web server reports that it is HTML.

Comment: Is there any way to debug it?

Comment: i found the solution. It was a browser cache issue. I tried it in incognito window and it works fine.